# Extract a window of rows following a set of one's in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like the following:

```
Day     val
Day1    0
Day2    0
Day3    0
Day4    0
Day5    1
Day6    1
Day7    1
Day8    1
Day9    0
Day10   0
Day11   0
Day12   1
Day13   1
Day14   1
Day15   1
Day16   0
Day17   0
Day18   0
Day19   0
Day20   0
Day21   1
Day22   0
Day23   1
Day24   1
Day25   1
```

I am looking to extract at-most 2 rows where `val = 0` but only those where the proceeding rows are a set of 1's.

For example:
There is a set of ones from `Day5` to `Day8` (an event). I would need to look into at-most two rows after the end of the event. So here it's `Day9` and `Day10`.

Similarly, `Day21` is a single-day event, and I need to look into only `Day22` since it is the single zero that follows the event.

For the table data above, the output would be the following:

```
Day     val    
day9    0
Day10   0
Day16   0
Day17   0
Day22   0
```

Comment: If Day23 was a 0, would it be included in the output or not?

Comment: yes , that should be included then @Shaido

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can simplify the condition for each row to:

- The `val` value should be 0
- The previous day or the day before that should have a `val` of 1

In code:

```
cond = (df['val'].shift(1) == 1) | (df['val'].shift(2) == 1)
df.loc[(df['val'] == 0) & cond]
```

Result:

```
      Day  val
8    Day9    0
9   Day10    0
15  Day16    0
16  Day17    0
21  Day22    0
```

---

Note: If more than 2 days should be considered this can easily be added to the condition `cond`. In this case, `cond` can be constructed with a list comprehension and [`np.any()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.any.html), for example:

```
n = 2
cond = np.any([df['val'].shift(s) == 1 for s in range(1, n+1)], axis=0)

df.loc[(df['val'] == 0) & cond]
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution @Shaido , would you be able to elaborate a bit on the `any` part please , i got the list comprehension

Comment: @rsp: I added an example with `any` as well. Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can compute a mask on the rolling max per group where the groups start for each 1->0 transition and combine it with a second mask where the values are 0:

```
N = 2
o2z = df['val'].diff().eq(-1)
m1 = o2z.groupby(o2z.cumsum()).rolling(N, min_periods=1).max().astype(bool).values
m2 = df['val'].eq(0)
df[m1&m2]
```

Output:

```
      Day  val
8    Day9    0
9   Day10    0
15  Day16    0
16  Day17    0
21  Day22    0
```

Comment: @rsp maybe the solution is too convoluted, I used a group approach to avoid artifacts if a longer N is used and not all values are 0/1, maybe that was premature optimization ;)

Comment: I think you can simplify the `m1` mask to be `m1 = o2z.rolling(N, min_periods=1).max()` which should remove the use of groupby. (I also got a downvote so I expect it to be someone considering the question as too simple and downvoting all answers as well.)

Comment: @Shaido I used `groupby` as it would be necessary if you have values other than 0/1 and N>2 to ensure a strech won't "contaminate" another group, but for 0/1/N=2 your solution is perfect